# Meteor and Bootstrap table, How to call detailFormatter function

Tags: javascript, meteor, bootstrap-table

I'm using [Bootstrap table](https://atmospherejs.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table)

[1](https://atmospherejs.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table): http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/ . I have added [This Package](https://atmospherejs.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table) to import Bootstrap-table.

```
     <table id="table" class="table table-striped"
       data-toolbar="#toolbar"
       data-detail-view="true"
       data-height="460"
       data-pagination="true"
       data-search="true"
       data-sort-name="name"
       data-sort-order="desc"
       data-unique-id="id"
       data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, ALL]"
       data-detail-formatter="detailFormatter"
       data-show-export="true"
       data-show-refresh="true"
       data-show-columns="true"
       data-row-style="rowStyle"
       data-export-types="['csv']">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">id</th>
        <th data-field="question" data-sortable="true">question</th>
        <th data-field="answer" data-sortable="true">answer</th>
        <th data-field="category" data-visible="true" data-tableexport-display="always">category</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Its working fine, but i have a **detailFormatter** function that must be called to create row detail stuff. basically am trying to achieve [This](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#methods/expandRow-collapseRow.html)

So in my js , I have added detailFormatter function , but not working, So where should i put **detailFormatter** function to work.

```
 if (Meteor.isClient) {

function detailFormatter(index, row) {
alert("detailFormatter 1")
                var html = [];
                $.each(row, function (key, value) {
                    console.log("key: "+key);
                    if(key=="answer") {
                        html.push('<p><b>' + key + ':</b> <textarea class="form-control">' + value + '</textarea> </p>');
                        html.push('<button type=button class=update-btn>Update</button>');

                    }
                    if(key=="category"){


                        console.log("category:: "+value)

                        if(value=="application_related"){
                                html.push('<select class="form-control"><option  selected value="application_related">Application Related</option><option value="application_status">Application Status</option></select>');
                        } else {
                            html.push('<select class="form-control"><option  selected value="application_related">Application Related</option><option value="application_status" selected>Application Status</option></select>');
                        }

                        $('select').first().val("application_status");

                        //$('select option[value="' + value + '"]')
                    }
                    if(key=="id"){
                         html.push('<input type="hidden" class="id" value='+ value + '></input>');
                        console.log("category:: "+value)
                    }
                });
                return html.join('');
        }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I've run into a similar issue with rowStyle when defined via HTML. The solution is to pass the functions to the table via JS. The same should apply to any function that needs to be passed to bootstrap-table.

For instance:

```
Template.results.onRendered(function(){
    this.$('#table').bootstrapTable({detailFormatter : myFormatterFunction, rowStyle : myRowStyleFunction});
};
```

Comment: Detail Formatter is suppose to create a new blank column in the table heading,but In my case the '+' Plus Symbol to expand the detail view is occupying the column of ID field of the table. I tried to find the solution, but couldn't find the one. help me if you can